# Laravel: Redirecting to a Secure Route with Query String Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4, you can generate a URL to a named route with the following code

```
$url = route('route-name');
$url = app('url')->route('route-name');    
$url = URL::to('route-name');
```

Is it possible to generate a **secure** URL (https) to a named route?

I know you can "force" a route to be secure when you set it up

```
Route::get('route-name', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

However, "force" (seems to?) mean making the route invisible to `http` based browsing.  The routing methods/functions don't pick up on this, and still generate `http` URLs.

To clarify, I've setup a route like this

```
Route::get('/stack-overflow', array('as'=>'route-name', function(){

}));
```

That's a route with a path of `stack-overflow` and a name of `route-name`.  I can generate a plaintext `http` link using the name (`route-name`).  I want to generate a secure `https` link using the **route name**, not the path.  I also want the generated URL to contain query string parameters

```
https://example.com/stack-overflow?foo=bar
```

Comment: There is a class `UrlGenerator` with `public function to($path, $extra = array(), $secure = null)`. I can't find a class `URL`...

Comment: @Rudie the `to` method generates a URL from a path -- I want to know the Laravel native way to generate a secure URL from a **named route**.  (also, google "Laravel facades" to learn about the URL/UrlGenerator difference)

Comment: If `$url = URL::to('route-name');` works, like you say, there is a class `URL` and you can see what it does. I can't find that class. Or do those 3 methods you mention NOT exist?

Comment: `to` method generates a URL from both path and named route, you may try `URL::to('route-name',[],true)` as @Rudie mentioned.

Comment: @razor Appreciate the help -- but `to` doesn't seem to work with named routes.  It generates a path to the literal route name.  Also, `to` doesn't allow you to add query string parameters, it only allows adding extra URL segments.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [URL::secure](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L134).

```
URL::secure('absolute/path');
//generates https://domain.com/absolute/path
```

With a named route:

```
URL::secure(URL::route('route-name'));
```

Comment: Does that work with a named route?  It seems like it expects the actual path, and not the route name defined in routes.php? (am I mistaken about that?)

Comment: @AlanStorm, It does if you send `URL::route`.

Comment: @Marwlln Thanks, appreciate the help! Does that actually work for you?  URL::route generates an HTTP URL string for me, but when I pass that string to URL::secure it doesn't seem to "https-ify" it.

Comment: @AlanStorm My original answer had a mistake, beside I've tested got confused with the generated URL, tested Marwelln solution and works for me in L4.1

Comment: @marcanuy No worries on the mistake, it's easy to get confused.  I'm on the latest 4.2.8, and its not working for me :(

Comment: `URL::secure(URL::route('route-name',[],false));` works in L4.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Capturing a comment from Razor above, you can use the following code to generate the sort of secure, query string parameter URL I was looking for in Laravel 4.2.8

```
//first parameter is the configured route name, second is the list of 
//query string parameters, the third parameter (`$absolute`), ensures
//the protocol and server is stripped from the return value (giving us /path/to/route
//vs. http://example.com/path/to/route
$url_path   = URL::route('route-name',['foo'=>'bar'],false);

//with the URL path generated, we can use the secure URL generation to
//turn that path into an https url 
$secure_url = URL::secure($url_path);
```